# sort.Slice does not sort correctly

Tags: sorting, go, slice

```
abc := []byte{'a', 'c', 'b'}  
sort.Slice(abc[1:], func(i, j int) bool {
  return abc[i] < abc[j]
})
fmt.Println(string(abc)) //print acb
```

The above code doesn't sort `abc` correctly. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you pass the `abc[1:]` subslice to sort, yet in your `less()` function you index the `abc` original (complete) slice. `sort.Slice()` will pass index values to `less()` based on the slice you pass to it to sort, and using those indices on another slice (the original), you will compare unintended elements and report false information to `sort.Slice()`.

If you use the same slice, it works:

```
sort.Slice(abc[1:], func(i, j int) bool {
    return abc[1:][i] < abc[1:][j]
})
```

It also works if you manually add the offset when indexing the original slice:

```
sort.Slice(abc[1:], func(i, j int) bool {
    return abc[1+i] < abc[1+j]
})
```

Of course it would be nicer, cleaner and more efficient to store this slice:

```
s := abc[1:]
sort.Slice(s, func(i, j int) bool {
    return s[i] < s[j]
})
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hI9-8FJtnGi).